# SUM hours in datetime SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get **ONLY** the total hour in a DATETIME column of my database.

This is my **database:** [image: db]

I tried this

```
SELECT SUM(DATEPART(hour, starts)) as Total_Hours
FROM assenze
```

But it gives me this error -> *FUNCTION calassenze.DATEPART does not exist*
(calassenze is the name of my Database)

I also tried this:

```
SELECT SUM(hour, starts) as Total_Hours
FROM assenze
```

same story, this is the error it gives me -> *syntass error in the QUERY SQL near ' starts) as Total_Hours
FROM assenze LIMIT 0, 25' line1*

I also tried this:

```
SELECT SUM(starts) as Total_Hours
  FROM assenze
```

But it gives me a werdly high number ->  [image: total]

I dont know how to get only the hours, if someone could help me, it would be so much appreciated

Comment: What RDBMS, MySQL maybe? Which doesn't have a datepart function.  By the way, I don't think adding up the hours from a timestamp is going to have any real value. Maybe you want to add up the difference between starts and ends?

Comment: I think yes, what i want is the total our between starts and ends. Like the first voice as a total of 8 hours. I know how much it is but i need to find a way to print it in my SQL

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you are trying to do. Include sample data (in your post, not an image), and your desired result.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). This also includes sample data; we can't copy/paste from an image to use to test possible solutions to your problem. Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate an issue, and that clearly isn't the case with test data. Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get ONLY the total hour in a DATETIME column of my database.

I suspect you really aren't, because such a value is meaningless - or at least, is not useful for reporting purposes.

From the comments:

> I think yes, what I want is the total hour between starts and ends. Like the first voice as a total of 8 hours. I know how much it is but i need to find a way to print it in my SQL

Actually the first row (`2202-05-25 08:30:00` to `2022-05-25 17:30:00` is 9 hours, not 8 hours).

Anyway, [use the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function to get the *time difference* between two `datetime` (or `timestamp`) values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff); and set the first parameter to `HOURS` to get that time-difference value quantified by the total number of hours between them.

```sql
SELECT
    t.*
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( hour, t.starts, t.ends ) AS TotalHours
FROM
    assenze AS t
```

You don't need to use `SUM` at all unless you're *aggregating over row groups*, which you don't appear to need to do as per my reading of your question.

...but if you did, then you'd do this:

```sql
SELECT
    t.ename,
    COUNT(*) AS CountRows,
    SUM( TIMESTAMPDIFF( hour, t.starts, t.ends ) ) AS TotalHours 
FROM
    assenze AS t
GROUP BY
    t.ename
```

I added the `COUNT(*)` column to help make it easier to see how `GROUP BY` works.